# Delete firestore collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an application with the following firestore data structure:

- groups

  - groupId

    - members

      - memberId

Now, when I want to delete a group, all it's members must be deleted accordingly. When I do this with a batched delete, the possibility exists that, when the client is offline, in the meanwhile new members are added so not everything will be deleted properly. How can I achieve this so everything about the group is properly removed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend implementing this in [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You can either trigger that directly with a [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), or through [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) itself.

The latter has the advantage that the "delete" command can be sent/queued by a client while it is not connected, and will then be synchronized and executed correctly when it is next online.

Comment: Would this also work when the documents & collections are secured with an author field limiting only owners to delete their data?

Comment: Guide to setting up a callable Cloud Function to recursively delete now in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Answer (score 2):

Using the firebase-cli:

```
firebase firestore:delete -r /<collection path>

firebase firestore:delete --all-collections
```

Comment: can the firebase cli target a firestore database? I thought it can only access the firebase realtime database